# How to wrap var img = new image with tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, word-wrap

Trying to preload images in a loop and it works fine but how to wrap each image with another tag. Doing this code won't work and I can't see a problem so far.

```
...
var img = new Image();
$(img).load(function(){
$(this).hide();         
$('.container').append('<a href="/">'+this+'</a>');                                                     $(this).fadeIn();                                       
});
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do `'<a href="/">'+this+'</a>'` when this is a DOMElement.

A good solution can be:

```
// Inside the callback
$('<a href="/"></a>').append(this).appendTo('.container');
```

Remember that if you use `.wrap` it will return the original element, not the wrapper!

Answer (score 3):

have you tried using $(this) rather than this.

or why dont you use:

```
  var $html = $(this).wrap('<a href="/" />');
  $('.container').append($html);
```

Comment: Also why are you hiding the image? Have you viewed your source to see if it's there but display is none?

Comment: Sorry, but your solution wont work either, i did it before and it would just return [object] or wont wrap at all... I am checking now @pier-paolo-ramon solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`$.wrap`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/)

```
$(img).wrap('<a href="#"></a>');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `wrap`

http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't know what to do w/ "this"... If you're not doing other further manipulation w/ the image at this step is it possible that you do this:

```
...
$('.container').append('<a href="/"><img id=' + anIdOfYourChoosing + ' /></a>');
...
```

and you just retroactively set properties on the image after the fact.